# Can I change the default folder that photos are uploaded to when using the Ubuntu One Files app for Android?

Tags: ubuntu-one, sync, android

I like that I can sync my Pictures from my Android phone to my computer with Ubuntu One, but I don't like that the folder appears in the root of my home directory.

Is there a way I can get the synced folder to reside in, for example, `~/Pictures/HTC Photos/` instead of `~/HTC Photos`?

Comment: I've noticed that I can now, through my phone, choose the name of the directory and place it within my Ubuntu One directory, which is good enough for me! I can just link to this directory from my Pictures directory.

Answer (score 1):

This functionality was recently added to the Android app so to change the default folder that photos are uploaded you can follow these steps:

- Firstly in Ubuntu create the new folder where you want the pictures
  to be uploaded to, then right click on the folder and select
  **Synchronise this Folder** from the Ubuntu One section in the menu:

[image]

- Now on your phone launch the Ubuntu One Files app and in the settings
  menu click on **Auto Upload Settings** then **Upload Photos to:**
- This will bring up a list of all the folders you are syncing, the new
  folders that you added in the first step should appear here
  (sometimes it won't appear though because the system won't have updated itself yet, if
  you cannot see the new folder try using the refresh button at the
  top, or navigating into a different folder and then back again and the
  system should have caught up with you)

Select the folder you wish to upload to and then press the menu button and select **Auto-upload here** from the menu, and this will be the new default folder that photos are uploaded to.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if your HTC can be configured to change the folder accordingly as I have no experience with an HTC, however I can show you how to do a variation of what you want with Linux/ Ubuntu.

- First, hide the HTC_Photos directory in your home directory by prepending a "**.**" to the directory name.
- Next, create a symlink in your Pictures Directory to your now hidden HTC Photos directory in your home folder.
- Lastly, change the name of the symlink in your Pictures directory to unhide it.

  ```
  cd /home/user/
  mv /home/user/HTC_Photos /home/user/.HTC_Photos
  cd /home/user/Pictures/
  ln -s /home/user/.HTC_Photos/ .
  mv /home/user/Pictures/.HTC_Photos /home/user/Pictures/HTC_Photos
  ```

It's a bit of a hack for the simple reason that the HTC Photos directory will still actually reside in your home directory, it just won't be visible.

Comment: When I rename the folder to hide it syncing is broken :/

Answer (score 0):

No, currently you cannot choose where to put the synced folders.

We have it in our wishlist, though!